# cisco Output Queue Droppped on down interface

Tags: cisco, interface

what does it mean if an interface is reported down but there are drops on the interface?

```
show interface X
```

displayed:
Total output drops: N
line protocol is down (notc)

Comment: Did any answer help you? if so, you should accept the answer so that the question doesn't keep popping up forever, looking for an answer. Alternatively, you could provide and accept your own answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to take in mind that interface counters will save it numbers, what you see on that is the last "Total output drops" meassure by the interfaces on the past where it was UP. If you want to check a new link, you need to clear the number, try:

```
[equipment]#clear counter *interface*
```

Once you tried that, all your counters will reset to 0, and when the interface goes UP, you will seeing really what is happening

Comment: thanks. If interfaces are not cleared regularily this could be a useful mechanism for determining interfaces that have not been in use for a longer time?

Comment: i don't thing so, cause, you will always see on that part, an acumulative measure, the part of the output that always change will be the total output and input. On some devices, like huawei, appears something like this, whe you can see what you want:                                                                                                      Last physical up time   : -
Last physical down time : -

Comment: Some thing that could help is this part:                                                        Last input xxxxxxx, output xxxxxx.                                                                                 If an interface is down, on this part you can calculate when was the last time where interface was UP.

Comment: sure, but when deciding between interfaces with output queue drops and ones without the safer assumption of longer downtime without looking at the entire output of show interface (cisco ios) would be the one with 0 output queue drops?

Comment: @Max, of course you can